# Verb [will] -- in [Door won't budge] and [Husband won't budge] -- same meaning?

Tags: meaning, verbs, dictionaries, animacy

> 1B. Battery won't hold a charge.
>
> 1N.  Noise from the device won't stop.
>
> 2D. [ Door is stuck and won't budge. ]
>
> 2H. [ Husband stuck on name and won't budge! ] --- (Baby Name Game)

For the auxiliary verb [will], three dictionaries I checked all have separate entries for

- (P). -- A person desiring or wishing something, and
- (Obj). -- An inanimate object having capability --- [the back seat will hold three passengers]

I believe that there is no difference between these two meanings (P) and (Obj), which you can confirm by trying to assign these two meanings to the 4 examples at the top.

(You will eliminate by deduction, [futurity] and other meanings.)

What do you think?

---

The (Obj) meaning  in the 3 dictionaries :

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will 
4 —used to express capability or sufficiency ---- [the back seat will hold three passengers]

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/will
6. (auxiliary) To be able to, to have the capacity to. [from 14th c.] ---- [ Unfortunately, only one of these gloves will actually fit over my hand. ]

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/will

8. am (is, are, etc.) capable of; can: [ This tree will live without water for three months.]

   5. used as an auxiliary to express capacity or ability: [this rope will support a load]

Comment: We generally don't think of inanimate objects as having desires and wishes. The back seat doesn't have any feelings about the number of persons who sit on it. A person would.

Comment: Sometimes the English pedantic Vegematic dices a little too finely.

Answer (score 3):

You have submitted a lengthy question, but what it boils down to is, in ***door won't budge*** and ***husband won't budge***, whether the *won't* (short for *will not*), in each case, has the same meaning.

All I would say is that we often ascribe human volition, not only with *will*, to inanimate things e.g. *the car won't start*, *my computer has lost all its memory*, *my oven keeps bleeping at me* etc.

One might also argue that the volitional *will* is actually only the future *will* in disguise. Isn't *the door will not open* only short for *if you push it, it will not open* (future tense).

Comment: I like your last paragraph best.  That's how the phrases come across to me.